# Get remaining aggregated column as list on group by two columns in python pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have total 5 columns and I want to group by on two columns and want to get other columns as in the list. I am using python pandas.
i am giving here one example

```
   BN            PN        tempC tempF humidity
0  7363311        1         28    82       73
1  7363311        2         27    81       73
2  7363311        3         27    81       73
3  7363311        4         27    81       73
4  7363311        4         27    81       73
5  7363311        5         27    81       73
8  7363311        7         27    81       73
9  7363311        7         27    81       74
```

and output should be like this below

```
  BN                  PN      tempC     tempF   humidity
   7363311            1         28        82       73
                      2         27        81       73
                      3         27        81       73
                      4         [27,27] [81,81]  [73,73]
                      5          27        81       73
                      7         [27,27] [81,81]  [73,74]
```

I am using below code to group by it

```
df.groupby(['BN','PN'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First it necessary aggregate `tuple` and then convert to `list`s:

```
df = df.groupby(['BN','PN']).agg(tuple).applymap(list)
print (df)
               tempC     tempF  humidity
BN      PN                              
7363311 1       [28]      [82]      [73]
        2       [27]      [81]      [73]
        3       [27]      [81]      [73]
        4   [27, 27]  [81, 81]  [73, 73]
        5       [27]      [81]      [73]
        7   [27, 27]  [81, 81]  [73, 74]
```

If want combination of `list`s with `scalar`s add `if-else` statement:

```
df = df.groupby(['BN','PN']).agg(tuple).applymap(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else list(x))
print (df)
               tempC     tempF  humidity
BN      PN                              
7363311 1         28        82        73
        2         27        81        73
        3         27        81        73
        4   [27, 27]  [81, 81]  [73, 73]
        5         27        81        73
        7   [27, 27]  [81, 81]  [73, 74]
```

Comment: getting error... ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Comment: ok i got it... correct solution is  df.groupby(['BN','PN']).aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x)).applymap(list)